# Database table name for events

Tags: civievent

I want to access the details of registered members for an event through database.So I want the table name in which the details of the registered participants will store.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your quesitons. Every question should include the version of CiviCRM you are using and the CMS and version it is paired with.  Then for this question you should state what you are trying to achieve and why you think you need to access the database directly.

Answer (score 3):

The table is called civicrm_participant which holds all the event participant record

If an single user is registering for multiple user then you can find the registered user using column name registered_by_id

I guess this help

Answer (score 2):

I am confused by 'registered members for an event' and assume you mean contacts that have registered for an event, not necessarily members (=contacts that have an active membership). The details of participants are stored in civicrm_participant

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need the database table?
The preferred way to access CiviCRM data is via the CiviCRM API.

It is very likely you can get the data you need, with a much lesser chance to harm the data integrity of your CiviCRM

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API